# Swift Optionals Clarifiaction Required

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

I hope someone can explain this to me.... (still quite new to Swift!)

This line fails if *part* is nil...

```
    cell?.myTextField.text = part?.number
```

> (fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional
>   value)

whereas this line works...

```
    cell?.myTextField?.text = part?.number;
```

In both cases, if cell is not nil, *myTextField* will exist. I would have thought that if *part* is nil, the line fails and *text* will not be set. But I have to set myTextField to an optional to get this line to 'pass'.

Can someone explain why this is? My confusion lies at having to append the ? to the end of *myTextField*.

Comment: What type the `myTextField` is? Is it `UITextField?` or `UITextField!`?

Comment: Its a UITextField defined in an ObjC class. I guess that make it a UITextField?

Comment: will part ever be nil?

Comment: Yes, part can be nil, as described in OP

Comment: I think the extra '?' is needed because cell may be nil (and isn't implicitly unwrapped) so you don't know that textfield is non nil. If you use '!' to unwrap the cell the second '?' won't be needed (but this will crash if cell is nil)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to recreate your issue, (mostly) with the following:

```
class Part {
    var number:String = "3"
}

class TextField {
    var text: String! = nil
}

class Cell {
    var myTextField: TextField! = nil
}

var part: Part? = nil
var cell:Cell? = Cell()

cell?.myTextField.text = part?.number    // crashes
cell?.myTextField?.text = part?.number   // works
```

It crashes because `myTextField` is an implicitly unwrapped optional, an since `cell` exists, but `myTextField` is `nil`, it crashes trying to unwrap the optional.

If you add a `?` to `myTextField`, the entire expression becomes an optional chain that results in `nil` because `myTextField` is `nil`.  In this case it doesn't crash because the optional chain doesn't try to unwrap `myTextField`.

The optional chain on the right hand of the assignment has no effect on whether the assignment happens or not.  If the optional chain on the right hand side of `=` is nil, then `nil` will be assigned to the left hand side.  Only the left hand side can cancel the assignment if it is an optional chain.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do this. That makes sense now. I've got to get used to the 'optional chaining' concept!